# AngularJS - Use Toaster Notification for Custom Exception Handling and Logging

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using [AngularJS Toaster](https://github.com/jirikavi/AngularJS-Toaster) for notification handling.

Now for custom exception handling, defined in **index.html** like below

```
<toaster-container toaster-options="{'time-out': 3000, 'position-class': 'toast-top-right'}"></toaster-container>
```

Using it in controller like below for custom exception

```
myService.serviceName().then(function (data) {
    //do some processing
    }).catch(function (error) {
    toaster.pop({
        type: 'error',
        title: 'Custom exception!'
    });
});
```

1. How can I use Angularjs-Toaster inside the decorator of
   $exceptionHandler ?
2. How can I use Angularjs-Toaster for logging specific errors ?
3. How can I use a common service for toaster notification for
   success,error and other messages ?

Comment: `.catch(myToasterService.error)` ??

Answer (score 0):

> AngularJS has its own exception handler. You can override it with a
>   Decorator that helps you to extend the functionality of an object in
>   AngularJS.

Move the code of showing toastr to custom exception handler, and in your service throw an exception which is handled by custom exception handler.

- So your service looks like these,

  ```
  myService.serviceName().then(function (data) {

      //Handle success

  }).catch(function (error) {

      // throw exception from catch handler
      throw new Error(error.msg);

  });
  ```
- Custom Exception Handler for showing toastr messages.

  ```
  angular.module('exceptionHandlingApp')
       .config(function($provide) {
           $provide.decorator('$exceptionHandler', 
               ['$delegate', 'toastr', function extendExceptionHandler($delegate, toastr) {
                    return function (exception, cause) {
                         exception.message = '[Error: ]' + exception.message;

                         // Use toastr service to show toastr msg.

                         toastr.pop({
                            type: 'error',
                            title: exception.message
                         });

                         $delegate(exception, cause);
                    };
              }]);
       });
  ```

Comment: How do I modify your above snippet in relations with code posted in question ?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: `exception.message` is undefined. Say I have status code mapped to error message, like `status = 1, msg = 'Please try again!'`. How do I show custom error message using above snippet ?

Comment: Excatly on which line in above snippet you got that undefined error.